# Is it possible to make MYSQL single thread to use multicore

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm looking for solution to make **mysql single thread to use multiple cores**

So basically one **heavy sql query will use multiple cores** to retrieve data faster, is that possible ?

Or is there such alternative in PostgreSQL, Oracle ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-general.html#faq-mysql-support-multi-core

Comment: @P.Salmon ok thank i didn't able to find in through google, can it be you have some good article how to enable it couse right now on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS i have there 4 cores mysql version is 5.7.31 it not wokring

Comment: How do you know MySQL is using one core only? Did you test it with multiple concurrent connections and queries?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes sure i tested, as you can see form this short video: https://recordit.co/j5KEzmbb5a when i visit my php pplication which uses one havy sql query from 4 cores of ubunt only 1 item goes to 100%. So i was above descripting single process multithreading

Comment: Mongo is definitely not an alternative. It is not even a SQL database. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL...

- In general, no more than 1 core is used for one connection.
- There are a few 'background' threads that make limited use of extra cores.  (Example:  keeping background I/O tasks moving.)
- In MySQL 8.0, a very few special cases will use multiple cores.  https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/23/mysql-8-0-14-a-road-to-parallel-query-execution-is-wide-open/
- If your table(s) is not fully cached, using multiple cores will be futile if it is already I/O-bound.
- The A.1.7 quote is misleading -- It is only saying that multiple connections can take advantage of multiple cores.  *And* "do the right thing" when they try to modify the same row(s).
- I filed https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100892 in hopes of getting them to fix the misleading nature of the entry.

Comment: Aha ok thanks for pointing all in details, but i want to understand if multicore cases which you describe need to be enabled from my end as person who setup MySQL ? or it by default already configured so ?

Comment: @Armen, No, there's nothing you need to do. MySQL works in this way by default. Each connection uses one thread and therefore one CPU. Multiple CPUs are utilized for user threads only if you run queries in multiple connections concurrently. The background threads used by InnoDB are not related to specific queries, but these also run by default, nothing you need to do to enable them.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you have it ([check MySQL answer A1.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-general.html#faq-mysql-support-multi-core)):

> [...] **MySQL is fully multithreaded, and will make use of multiple CPUs**, provided that the operating system supports them.

In PostgreSQL it is possible ([check their official FAQ](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#How_does_PostgreSQL_use_CPU_resources.3F)):

> [...] **Since version 9.6, portions of some queries can be run in parallel, in separate OS processes, allowing use of multiple CPU cores**. Parallel queries are enabled by default in version 10 (max_parallel_workers_per_gather), with additional parallelism expected in future releases.

For the other databases I wouldn't expect not to be, but a quick google search could help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, and is there some special steps to enable it ? I'm using   `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` i have there 4 cores `mysql version is 5.7.31`

Comment: AFAIK, MySQL should automatically use multiple cores, if your Ubuntu supports that. However, I think there might be specific tuning configuration that you should check for your specific OS.

Comment: Form this short video: recordit.co/j5KEzmbb5a when i visit my php application which uses one havy sql query from 4 cores of ubunt only 1 item goes to 100%. So i was above descripting single process multi threading

Comment: @Jzbach - A1.7 is misleading.  MySQL does _not_ do what you described; see my Answer.

Comment: @RickJames oh yeah, you are right. Small misunderstanding! Thanks for resolving it :)